# Generate automatically List of Definitions in appendix

Tags: appendices

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[francais, english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\begin{figure}
a
\caption{haha}
\end{figure}
~\cite{cr:sas:12}
% ------------------------------------------
% Bibliography
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4mm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{thesis}
% ------------------------------------------
% List of figures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
% ------------------------------------------
% List of Definitions
\chapter*{List of Definitions}
\markboth{List of Definitions}{List of Definitions}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}List of Definitions}
\makeatletter
\@starttoc{lod}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

The `List of Figures` generated is as follows:

[image]

However, I don't know how to add `Definition` so that the `List of Definitions` are automatically generated. Could anyone help?

Comment: Probably you want something like the `glossaries` package for this?

Comment: Actually, you want [glossaries](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) if you want to include the definitions in the list. If you want a list which points to definitions elsewhere (a list of words defined rather than a list of definitions themselves), you might try something like [tocloft](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft). \[I expect [etoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) could also be used as it seems to be able to pretty much do anything with ToCs and the like, but you probably don't need that here.\]

Comment: Actually, someone gave me the `pdf` of his whole paper, and the `tex` files (with macros but without main content), which compiles well. I can see that in his `pdf` file, the `List of Definitions` is well generated. I also see that he doesn't use package `glossaries`, `tocloft` or `etoc`. However, as the main content has been removed, I cannot see how he added a `Definition`...

Comment: I don't understand. If you already have the macros and they work well, what's the problem? In any case, anything you can do with a package, you can do without the package. But doing that when a package exists to do what you want is just reinventing the wheel. (You could do without LaTeX and format everything in plain TeX but you might not want to.) But anyway, if you have the macros and you say they work well, I don't understand why you are asking here at all.

Comment: I think I have all the macros which compile well. But I cannot see how he used these macros. For example, he might add some special commands when he entered a definition, so that this definition can be added to the list...

Comment: If you want to use those macros, why don't you include them in your question? You are asking people to come up with solutions which will work with specific code without sharing that code.

Comment: Well, I don't think there is any macro related to `starttoc`...

Comment: No. But the list will only be generated if you write the list to the file. You can use `\addcontentsline` for that but you need to show how you are adding definitions to your document. (If you don't add any definitions, there is nothing to put in the list.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, francais, english]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listofdefnitionsname}{List of Definitions}% based on page 13 of tocloft's manual
\newlistof{definition}{defn}{\listofdefnitionsname}
\newcommand{\definition}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{definition}
  \par\noindent\textbf{Definition \thedefinition. \textbf{#1:} #2}
  \addcontentsline{defn}{definition}{\protect\numberline{\thedefinition}#1}\par}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Chapter}
  \section{Section}
  \begin{figure}
    a
    \caption{haha}
  \end{figure}
  ~\cite{cr:sas:12}
  \definition{This}{This is a definition.}
  % ------------------------------------------
  % Bibliography
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4mm}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\bibname}
  \bibliographystyle{alpha}
  \bibliography{thesis}
  % ------------------------------------------
  % List of figures
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\listfigurename}
  \listoffigures
  \cleardoublepage
  % ------------------------------------------
  % List of Definitions
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}\listofdefnitionsname}
  \listofdefinition
\end{document}
```

You don't show how you are adding definitions so I just put a placeholder macro in based on the `tocloft` example. Obviously, you can modify this to suit.

[image: lod]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which works... I will see if there is other solution without using these packages...